# Guava's ComparisonChain conversion to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, comparisonchain

I'm converting some code to JavaScript from Java, and I've come across this code:

```
static final Comparator<Point> compareXCoord = new Comparator<Point>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Point o1, Point o2) {
        return ComparisonChain.start().
                compare(o1.x, o2.x).
                compare(o1.y, o2.y).
                result();
    }
};

static final Comparator<Point> compareYCoord = new Comparator<Point>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Point o1, Point o2) {
        return ComparisonChain.start().
                compare(o1.y, o2.y).
                compare(o1.x, o2.x).result();
    }
};

...

Arrays.binarySearch(ypoints, Point.make(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, ymin),
            compareYCoord);
```

Seems fair enough, as it'll return the resultant object of the matching comparison chain.

But what I don't understand is that both methods seem to my naive eyes to do the exact same thing: return if either the `x` or `y` properties match.  The only difference is the first checks the `x` property first, i.e., the order of the checks is different.

Also, if that's true, then the `Arrays.binarySearch` method will return `ypoints` elements with equal `x` properties. I don't feel this is what the function is intended to do.

So, my JavaScript translation would be:

```
function compareXCoord(p1, p2) {
  return (p1.x === p2.x) ? p1 : 
         (p1.y === p2.y) ? p1 : undefined;
}

function compareYCoord(p1, p2) {
  return (p1.y === p2.y) ? p1 : 
         (p1.x === p2.x) ? p1 : undefined;
}
```

But both of these could be simplified to `return (p1.y === p2.y || p1.x === p2.x) ? p1 : undefined;`.

I feel I'm certainly misunderstanding how `ComparisonChain` works. Is the order of the chain important? Bonus points for directions into how to translate this to JavaScript.

Comment: These comparators differ on how they compare `(1, 2)`  to `(2, 1)`. `compareXCoord` will say `(1, 2) < (2, 1)` and `compareYCoord` will say `(1, 2) > (2, 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bear in mind that the Java [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) return value is three-valued (i.e. higher, lower, or equal).  Thus the order in which you compare the coordinates is important - sorting by `x` first is not the same as sorting by `y` first.